# This project does not use the Gradle build system warning to imported Boofcv into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, template-matching, boofcv

So, Finally I have install BoofCV into Android Studio (Tx to Q&A on this website) and all examples are running perfectly by opening pop up windows (including Template Matching and Webcam Capture):

[image: Screenshot]

but message in Event Log [says], 'Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.' So, what changes should I do!?

I want to create an app of Template matching via Webcam. Is it possible to create my app ignoring above warning message.!?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You are having this error because you started the android project by just opening it on android studio.

Here is the fix, instead Import the project like this:

File -> New-> import project

And Voila, the issue will be resolved.